# AWS - boto3 - how to list of all the ORG IDs(even nested) under organization

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get a list of all the org ids under organization using boto3. The current structure is like this -

```
                          Root
                            |
                            |
                    ou1-----OU2-----OU3
                     |      |        |
                    ou4    ou5      ou6
                     |
                    ou7
                     |
                    ou8
```

This structure may change in future more ORG units might get added some of them may be deleted so I would like to make the function dynamic. I was hoping I could provide the Root id after which it should be able to find out all the org id under it. But this seems a little complicated as there is no existing API in boto3 which lists all the ORG ids under root. I would really appreciate if someone could give guidance/suggestion

I have taken a look at -
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.list_children

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.list_parents

but not sure how to interconnect them so it can find all the org ids, below is the code that I wrote but this will only fetch 2nd layer of children, that is till org4,5 and 6

```
org = session.client("organizations")
    response = org.list_roots()
    for PolicyTypes in response["Roots"]:
        parent_id = PolicyTypes["Id"]
    OUlist = []
    NextToken = False
    while NextToken is not None:
        if not NextToken:
            response_iterator = org.list_organizational_units_for_parent(ParentId=parent_id, MaxResults=20)
        else:
            response_iterator = org.list_organizational_units_for_parent(ParentId=parent_id, MaxResults=20,
                                                                         NextToken=NextToken)
        OUlist = get_OUlist(OUlist, response_iterator)
        try:
            NextToken = response_iterator['NextToken']
        except KeyError:
            break

    get_child_ou(org, OUlist)



def get_child_ou(org, OUlist):
    for ou in OUlist:
        NextToken = False
        while NextToken is not None:
            if not NextToken:
                response_iterator = org.list_children(ParentId=ou, ChildType='ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT', MaxResults=20)
            else:
                response_iterator = org.list_children(ParentId=ou, ChildType='ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT', NextToken=NextToken,
                                                      MaxResults=20)
            try:
                NextToken = response_iterator['NextToken']
            except KeyError:
                break
    for orgid in response_iterator["Children"]:
        OUlist.append(orgid["Id"])
    return OUlist
```

Comment: You have the creds for the organization's master account?

Comment: @helloV yes I have

Comment: then use list_accounts(). https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.list_accounts

Comment: list_accounts() does not return ORG ID

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Danish's answer:

You can now use the [Paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html) feature for *organizations.list_children* (and many other API calls). This drops the need to check for NextToken, saves LOCs and enhances code readability :-)

```
# Lambda example
import boto3

client = boto3.client('organizations')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  root_id    = client.list_roots()['Roots'][0]['Id']
  ou_id_list = get_ou_ids(root_id)

  print(ou_id_list)


def get_ou_ids(parent_id):
  full_result = []

  paginator = client.get_paginator('list_children')
  iterator  = paginator.paginate(
    ParentId=parent_id,
    ChildType='ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT'
  )

  for page in iterator:
    for ou in page['Children']:
      # 1. Add entry
      # 2. Fetch children recursively
      full_result.append(ou['Id'])
      full_result.extend(get_ou_ids(ou['Id']))

  return full_result
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
org = session.client('organizations')


def printout(parent_id, indent):
    print(f"{'-' * indent} {parent_id}")
    paginator = org.get_paginator('list_children')
    iterator = paginator.paginate(
        ParentId=parent_id,
        ChildType='ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT'
    )
    indent += 1
    for page in iterator:
        for ou in page['Children']:
            printout(ou['Id'], indent)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rootid = org.list_roots()["Roots"][0]["Id"]
    printout(rootid, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3

def add_ou(ids):
    for id in ids:
        ou_list.append(id)
        child_ids = get_childs(id)
        while child_ids:
            if len(child_ids) > 1:
                add_ou(child_ids)
                child_ids = []
            else:
                ou_list.append(child_ids[0])
                child_ids = get_childs(child_ids[0])

def get_childs(id):
    childs = org_client.list_children(
    ParentId=id,
    ChildType='ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT')
    return [child["Id"] for child in childs["Children"]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    org_client = boto3.client('organizations')
    root_id = org_client.list_roots()["Roots"][0]["Id"]
    childs = get_childs(root_id)
    ou_list = []
    add_ou(childs)
    print(ou_list)
```

This will loop through all organization units and print organization units Ids